# How to kill any running excel process?

Tags: c#

I want to kill all the excel process which are running in the system before I start my application.How can I do that in C#?

Comment: check my answer, this is a duplicate most likely though.

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL"))
{
    p.Kill();
}
```

Comment: I took out the .EXE as the process name is supposed to be a "friendly name" as defined by the MSDN, a name without file extension.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
try
{
      foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL.EXE"))
          p.Kill();
}
```